# get user credentials in a WSO2 ESB scheduled task

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I'm writing a sheduled task in WSO2 ESB who execute an external program. I want to send credentials informations of the WSO2 user to those programs when i run the task.
Is there any way to make it ??

Best regards

Comment: can you give more details about this?

Comment: I should create a scheduled task who run some shell scripts stored in differents unix machines. For each one, i must have credentials to open connection (i managed to create same user/pwd for WSO2 and the unix machines)

Answer (score 0):

I think the pattern you are using here is not right. The proper way to do this is not to use a task to send the credentials, rather use the user manager to get the 3rd party system to authenticate against the ESB's user store directly.